# How to block user from changing to other apps

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to make an activity in my native android app that doesn't allow to change to other apps, or open settings or go back to home screen, just like the alarm apps do when the alarm comes in, but I can't find anything about how to do this.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Try looking at [Lock Task mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=6E03F0FFDF894AAA818680C5123ECEE8).

Comment: Or u can use` onPause` and a `PendingIntent` using `Alarm` to shoot focus back on app again